# Browser Option in View Result Tree

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Unable to get Browser Option in JMeter 3.3 in View Result Tree in Solaris OS. Following it the photo of **Windows** OS where it is working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: you don't have samplers yet. it should work with sampler results

Comment: The photo is of Window's OS, Actually I am unable to get this option in Solaris

Answer (score 2):

Browser renderer uses [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), which is [not supported on Solaris](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Kiril S. answer, If you need to view in Browser mode the results, 
A workaround will be to save jtl file in Solaris and open this jtl file in windows by clicking Browse on [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

> To read existing results and display them, use the file panel Browse button to open the file.